# ZF2 : How to call a view helper in a service?

Tags: javascript, ajax, service, zend-framework2, viewhelper

I need use a view helper (***myPaginationControl***) in this service:

```
/.../
class TotoDisplayService implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    public function getReponse ($paginator)
    {
        $tab = '<table>';
        /.../

        $tab .= myPaginationControl($paginator, 'sliding','pagination_control_file',array('route' => 'paginator'));

        /.../
        foreach ($paginator as $t) {
            //something to list : THIS WORKS
        }
        $tab .= '</table>';

        return array(
            'result' => $tab
        );
    }
/.../
```

This service is called by this controller:

```
public function displayAction()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        // query to database
    $q1 = $this->serviceLocator->get('toto_list_service');
    $rep1 = $q1->getReponse($em);

    $paginator = new PaginatorZF(new DoctrinePaginator(new PaginatorORM($rep1)));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber ($this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1))->setItemCountPerPage(25);

        // prepares something to display with javascript
    $q2 = $this->serviceLocator->get('toto_display_service');
    $rep2 = $q2->getReponse($paginator);

        // return to javascript 
    return new JsonModel(
        $rep2
    );
}
```

Here is MyPaginationControl (the same as paginationControl, I did it for test)

```
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class MyPaginationControl extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($a, $b, $c, $d)
    {
        $PaginationControl = $this->getView()->plugin('paginationcontrol');

        return $PaginationControl($a,$b,$c,$d);
    }
}
```

Here is module.config.php

```
    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array (
            'toto_list_service' => 'Com\Service\Invokable\TotoListService',
            'toto_display_service' => 'Com\Service\Invokable\TotoDisplayService'
        )
    ),
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'myPaginationControl' => 'Com\View\Helper\MyPaginationControl',
            ),
    ),
```

Here is module.php (nothing special)

```
class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                   __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . tr_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
}
```

Here the error message:
    **Call to undefined function Com\Service\Invokable\MyPaginationControl() in D:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Gestion\module\Com\src\Com\Service\Invokable\TotoDisplayService.php**

And this controller is called by javascript (AJAX).
All works when I comment the line :
***$tab .= myPaginationControl(...***

I verified that my view helper myPaginationControl perfectly works when I use it in a phtml file.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller do this:

`$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get("toto_display_service")`

Please, not that this is not the best solution. Instead I would suggest you to pass the viewhelper with a factory via the __constructor(){}

```
namespace Application\Factory\Controller;

use Application\Controller\MyClassNameController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager;

class MyCLassNameFactory
{
    /**
     * @{inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __invoke(ControllerManager $controllerManager)
    {
        $serviceLocator = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();

        $controller = new MyClassNameController(
            $serviceLocator->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('toto_display_service');
        );

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

and in MyClassController

```
class MyClassNameController extends ADD_ANOTHER_CONTROLLER
{
   private $todoService = null;

    public function __construct($todoService = null)
    {
       $this->todoService = $todoService
    }
}
```

After that add the config in Module.php or module.config.php. I prefer the module.config.php file.

```
'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            'Application\Controller\MyClassName'        => 'Application\Factory\Controller\MyClassNameFactory'
    ],
],
```

Don't forget to remove the controller from the invokables or it won't work and you will get a collision

## Edit

`$tab .= myPaginationControl` should be  `$tab .= new myPaginationControl` or  `$tab .= $this->myPaginationControl`

if the above doesn't work dump the contents of `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')` find `myPaginationControl` and call it like that
`$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get("myPaginationControl");`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. There is something that I don't understand in your answer : I intended to call a view helper from a service. "toto_display_service" is not a view helper; do you suggest me to change it ?

Comment: Oh, i thought that your todo_display_service is a view helper. In this case show me `myPaginationControl`, Module.php and module.config.php codes. Also, I need the error you get when you use the paginator. 

The code I showed you was how to create a view helper and use it in your .phtml files

Comment: Here is MyPaginationControl that is in fact the same as paginationControl (it was for test !) :

Comment: All what you asked for is above. Thank you very much